# NodeJS server error while running two servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, server, node-modules

I have two NodeJS directories with same files except that the main one is running on PORT 8080 and other on PORT 9000. I am getting the following error while running the second service:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'mode' must be a 32-bit unsigned integer or an octal string. Received '0o777'
```

I have defined PORT using

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; //main one

var port = process.env.PORT || 9000; //second one in a different directory with same files
```

The error is thrown on this piece of code:

```
Redis.Promise.onPossiblyUnhandledRejection(function(error) {
    error.command ? logger.error(error, {name: error.command.name, args: error.command.args}) : logger.error(error);
});
```

The same thing is working as expected in another system but my system throws this error at the terminal. I have searched for it but cannot find a possible solution. All I am doing is running *node server.js* in both directories. What can be the possible reason for this?

Comment: how do you specify the port? can you edit adding this piece of code?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: can you add a larger piece of code? like where you instantiate the server and where you listen to connections

Comment: Would you post the code where you are passing the `mode` parameter? It seems like the error is there

Comment: It may also be an issue with permissions. `0o777 ` seems suspicious

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to change the directory permission from 0o777 to 511 (octal string) in the system configuration.